# "create-react-app my-app" is not recognized

Tags: react-native, react-redux, yarnpkg

I ran "yarn add global react-native-cli", following by "yarn add react-native". By then, everything seemed correctly installed.

I then used "create-react-native-app my-app" which leads to "zsh: command not found: create-react-app".

I tried to find something relevant on other posts with the same problem, but I didn't find anything close to solve my problem.

Does anyone know why the command is not working? And what should I be doing so I can create a new React app?

Thanks !

OSX HIGH SIERRA 10.13.6

PS : here's the app that I'd like to create 
https://medium.com/better-programming/bitcoin-ripple-ethereum-price-checker-with-react-native-redux-e9d076037092

Comment: You can try it with npm
npm i -g create-react-native-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install react with `npm install -g create-react-native-app`, you need to create the app with npx, npm, or yarn.

So the command to create a new app folder would be `npx create-react-app app-name-here`

This link to the React Github explains all of the ways you can create the app: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

You should run

`npm install -g create-react-native-app`

then

`create-react-native-app my-app`

Just read the link you posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer, it's "yarn create react-app react-native-redux-crypto-tracker".
Actually, I purposely did not use "npm" since I've been using "yarn" from the get go with my apps.

Thank for the help anyway.:-)

Comment: setup here : 

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md#getting-started